# Android System Resources Get Text dynamically

Tags: android, settings, system

I would like to set some specific system settings of android within my application. 
Is it possible to get the text and maybe also a description of the settings resources by code?

For instance I would like to allow to change this setting:

android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS
In the android settings it appears Brighness. This resource is localized as well, so I do not want to do the same thing within my appliacation.
I would like to create a button and insert the text dynamically, if possible.

If someone has a hint were to look at, please help.

Best Regards,

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

> android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS In the android
>   settings it appears Brighness. This resource is localized as well, so
>   I do not want to do the same thing within my appliacation.

See this: [Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#putInt%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29). If you want the value localized, use an integer resource in folders with language and/or locale qualifiers. See [Integer Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer) and [Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#creating-alternatives)

> I would like to create a button and insert the text dynamically, if
>   possible.

Define as much of the layout as possible in xml, calling setContentView() on the name of the xml file. The button can then be referenced after the call with (Button)findViewById() using the id as given in xml. You can then set text dynamically and modify the widget further in code. See [Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and [TextView setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), which works for Button since Button extends TextView.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello,thanks for the answer. I do not want to use an own defined resource for e.g. Brightness. I would like to get the resource from the origin. Google has this property defined and they have the resources already. Do I get somehow the resource id, from the original location? Otherwise I would need to write the texts on my own. And one has to do it in a way that the translation matches the one used by google to not mislead people in terms of which property by google is influenced by setting my one.